# File are shown but not directories

Tags: php, directory, scandir

so this code does what it should to list down files from a directory..but it also shows the directory..I want to remove it..is using scandir wrong?

```
    <ul>
<?php echo "List of files"?>
<?php
$dir = 'kcfinder/upload/files';
$files = scandir($dir);

foreach($files as $ind_file){
?>

<li><?php echo $ind_file;?> </a> | <a href="includes/delete.php?file=<?=$ind_file?>">Delete</a></li>
<?php
}
?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `is_file` function, you can check whether the current item is a file or not.

Try this code

```
if(is_file($dir . $ind_file)) {
 // You code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [`is_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php) inside of your `foreach` statement.

#### Like So:

```
$dir = 'kcfinder/upload/files';
$files = scandir($dir);

foreach ($files as $ind_file) {
  if (is_file(__DIR__.'/'.$ind_file)) {
    ?>
    <li><?php echo $ind_file;?> </a> | <a href="includes/delete.php?file=<?=$ind_file?>">Delete</a></li>
    <?php
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `if(is_dir($ind_file))` for get directory and `if (is_file($ind_file))` for files

```
$full_path = "kcfinder/upload/files";

if ($handle = opendir("$full_path")) 
{ 
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) 
    { 
        if(is_dir($full_path."/".$file))
        {
            if($file!='..' && $file!='.')
            {               
             //for folders  
            } 
       }else
       {
          //for files
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, you should be using `is_file()` and `scandir()`; Also, never put a function call in a `while` statement if you can avoid it.

Comment: thanks to your comment,but I have using this for my own file manager and I have not any problem whit it. Are you saying that I have using bad codes?

Comment: Yes it works, but it is bad coding practice. It encourages redundant coding and wastes resources. See the edit I made to your answer for the correct way to do it.

Comment: Oops! Okay I will improve my codes whatever I have not any problem with them .

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
<?php echo "List of files"?>
<?php
$dir = 'kcfinder/upload/files';
$files = scandir($dir);

foreach($files as $ind_file=>$afile){
  if($ind_file!=0 & $ind_file!=1){ // skip '.' and '..'
?>
<li><?php echo $afile;?> </a> | <a href="includes/delete.php?file=<?=$afile?>">Delete</a></li>
<?php
  }
}
?>
</ul>
```